# How I can trigger a function with a button click which is already set to be triggered with "Enter" Key press in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I was trying to make it possible to add a product to the cart by a button click beside the ENTER key press(which is now the only way to add a product to the cart), I have tried many times but unfortunately all ways does not work at all. 
This is a POS system project built with AngularJS (which my experience in it, is very weak) And I need to make it badly
here is the HTML part:

```html
<tr>
    <td colspan="6" class="text-center">

        <input autofocus autocomplete="off" list="product-list"
               id="product-entry" type="text" class="form-control"
               name="product-reference" required/><br/>

        <button id="myButton" ng-click="" >Add Product to Sale</button>

        <datalist id="product-list">
            <option ng-repeat="item in inventory" value="{{ item.name }}">
            </option>
        </datalist>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I need to make it when someone click "myButton" ,I imagine that I need to add some function in ng-click directive,But Any other ways are welcomed

And Here is the JS part :

```
        // POS Section
pos.controller('posController', function ($scope, $routeParams, Inventory, Transactions) {

  $scope.barcode = '';

  function barcodeHandler (e) {

      $scope.barcodeNotFoundError = false;

      $scope.barcode = $('#product-entry').val();

      var regex=/^[0-9]+$/;

      // if enter is pressed
      if (e.which === 13) {

        if(!$scope.barcode.match(regex)){
          for(var i = 0; i < $scope.inventory.length; i++) {
            if($scope.inventory[i].name === $scope.barcode) {
              $scope.barcode = $scope.inventory[i].barcode;
              break;
            }
          }
        }

        if ($scope.isValidProduct($scope.barcode)) {
          $scope.addProductToCart($scope.barcode);
          $scope.barcode = '';
          $scope.productsList = '';
          $scope.$digest();
          $('#product-entry').val($scope.barcode);
        }
        else {
          window.alert('product not found: ' + $scope.barcode);
          console.log('invalid product: ' + $scope.barcode);
          // $scope.barcodeNotFoundError = true;
        }
      }
  }

  $('#product-entry').off('keypress').on('keypress', barcodeHandler);
```

Comment: I assume this is inside a `<form>` tag if it's submitting on enter? If you add the attribute `type="submit"` to the button, it should submit the form on click

Comment: I tried this, but also not working :(

Comment: I misread and answered before reading the code. I added an answer below.

Comment: I realize that you have received and accepted an answer, but I have to caution you on the road you are on here mixing jQuery and AngularJS. Both are DOM manipulation frameworks and continuing on this path will lead to frustration and difficult to find bugs in the long run. Instead of using jQuery to retrieve or set values (`$('#product-entry').val()`) you should be using two-way binding via `ng-model`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing is listening for a keyup event on the field, and if that key matches the return key, it continues with your logic.

If you move the logic into its own function (before barcodeHandler), you can access it elsewhere:

```
$scope.doSomething = function() {
  $scope.barcodeNotFoundError = false;
  $scope.barcode = $('#product-entry').val();
  var regex=/^[0-9]+$/;

  if(!$scope.barcode.match(regex)){
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.inventory.length; i++) {
      if($scope.inventory[i].name === $scope.barcode) {
        $scope.barcode = $scope.inventory[i].barcode;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  if ($scope.isValidProduct($scope.barcode)) {
    $scope.addProductToCart($scope.barcode);
    $scope.barcode = '';
    $scope.productsList = '';
    $('#product-entry').val($scope.barcode);
  }
  else {
    window.alert('product not found: ' + $scope.barcode);
    console.log('invalid product: ' + $scope.barcode);
    // $scope.barcodeNotFoundError = true;
  }
};
```

Then inside barcodeHandler, use:

```
if (e.which === 13) {
  $scope.doSomething();
}
```

Now in your markup, You can do:

```
<button id="myButton" ng-click="doSomething()">Add Product to Sale</button>
```

Adding something to the `$scope` of the controller is a way of making it available in the view.

Comment: Thanks for your reply 
I tried what you said here but this was the console :

angular.js:11706 ReferenceError: regex is not defined
    at n.$scope.doSomething (pos.js:154)
    at angular.js:12474
    at f (angular.js:21700)
    at n.$eval (angular.js:14570)
    at n.$apply (angular.js:14669)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:21705)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLButtonElement.v.handle (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: then I tried to put this "  var regex=/^[0-9]+$/; " inside the doSomething() function 
it works but even if the product name is inside the input it gives me that : "product not found"

Comment: Apologies, the code is untested and I assumed your level of JS knowledge. You should move everything else inside the new function (where you define things to be used). I've updated the answer

Comment: Sorry bro for your effort with me. It works but it takes the first product in the database every time even I write any other product. and the console gives me that error: "angular.js:11706 Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.20/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply
    at angular.js:38
    at p (angular.js:14924)
    at n.$digest (angular.js:14366)
    at n.$scope.doSomething (pos.js:169)
    at angular.js:12474
    at f (angular.js:21700)
    at n.$eval (angular.js:14570)"

Comment: Did you try removing $scope.digest(); from your code? I don't know why you're forcing a digest there.

Comment: I removed it " $scope.digest();" the error disappeared , but still takes the first product every time

Comment: Does it do that when you hit 'enter'? Try logging `$scope.inventory[i].name` and `$scope.barcode` just before the if statement inside the for loop

Comment: Thank you very very very much. It worked at last, I cannot find the words you deserve .
By The way it was my fault that all products were with the same barcode that means the problems was solved earlier
Thank you again bro :) :D

Comment: No problem. Feel free to show appreciation with an upvote and marking the answer as accepted :)